# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found -hibernate-spring mvc--

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate

I have just created a simple Spring MVC web application while I am running in a server I am getting 404 [here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/882Ij.png) 
and this I have uploaded my enter project in github [git link](https://github.com/kaluvaomprakash/spring) and please check it and any help is appreciated 
>

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for index.html in your webcontent folder which is unfortunately not there.
You have used class level path on your controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
```

Try `/paperpay/customers`

Comment: it's not working tried with /paperpay/customers  and moreover I have added index.html  once check with the code git link I have updated with new index.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to type URL like http://localhost:8080/customers/ instead of http://localhost:8080/paperpay/ because of your controller mapping customers, not paperpay.

Comment: it's not working tried with /paperpay/customers  and moreover I have added index.html  once check with the code git link I have updated with new index.html